# Adding custom domain to CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Setting up CloudFront with an s3 bucket.

Adding a custom domain with ssl certificate.

Also added an A-record in Route 53.

Able to access the CloudFront distribution with default domain over HTTPS but not able to access custom domain, getting:

> This site can’t be reached

Added ssl certificate with alternate domain and a record in Route 53.

Comment: What do you mean by "added an A-record in Route 53"? Shouldn't it be a `CNAME` record?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein A-record which is pointing to cloudfront domain. which i have created in Route53 and Cname is added in cloudfront properties

Comment: An `A` record is used to point to an IP address. If you want to point your DNS Name to a CloudFront URL, you would use a `CNAME` record. See: [Differences Among A, CNAME, ALIAS, and URL records - DNSimple Help](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-between-a-cname-alias-url/)